# How can I schedule timer to power on and off device?

Tags: automation, power-on

Is there any way to schedule timer to power on and off device?

Example daily power on at 8am and power off at 10pm.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the device that you are using, this setting can easily be configured, in fact it comes natively on some devices like Xiaomi (MIUI), LG, Oneplus or Lenovo.

For example on my device running MIUI 9, I can easily configure the timer like so:

Open the Security App → Battery → Settings (Gear icon on top right corner) → Schedule power on or off:

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Enter time setting and tap OK, you're all set!.

Alternatively this feature can also be configured on some android ROMs:

- Settings → Advanced → Scheduled Power On / Off.
- Configure as needed.

[image: IMG:]

**Another workaround:**

> If neither of these options is available, then you could simply take
>   the advantage that your android device can be woken up by an alarm
>   even if its in the off state:
>
> - This workaround simply requires any android app capable of turning off the device at scheduled time e.g Tasker, Automate, Macrodroid etc
> - Then set an ideally **silent alarm** (e.g stock CM11S alarm (with a silent alarm) to power on the device.

<sup>Credits Oneplus forum: *[Schedule power on and off](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/schedule-power-on-and-off.209650/)*</sup>

Comment: A perfect and simple checklist. Thanks! After going through each option I've discovered that the scheduled power on is not available on Nokia C01 Plus. I've checked all these possibilities, and it's simply not there in any form. I mention this as a known "for instance", as there are probably many others. It would interesting to know whether the feature is mostly there, or mostly not there.