# Schedule power off/on in 8.1.10 Oreo

Tags: battery-life, 8.1-oreo, power-on

I just got a new 'phone running Android 8.10 Oreo, and I can't find the schedule power off/on anywhere.

Has the feature been removed? If not, where can I find it; I realize that this might vary by device, but there can only be afew places to look ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hasn't been a stock Android feature. Some sources including this [Missing "Scheduled Power On/Off" option in Android 5.0.2 on Swipe Elite Plus phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/196553) talk of it being on Lollipop but I jumped that version so can't comment

For sure, it's not a stock feature from 6.0 to 8.1. You can use some [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app to schedule power off not power on

Comment: MIUI ROMs used to have this, I don't know if it still does... There was some debate over whether it actually shutdown or going into somekind of "deep sleep" mode rather than actually shutting off. Also, some custom ROMs have a scheduled shutdown option (CM11 comes to mind but not positive), but not to power back on. Not sure I understand a real need for this feature with DND being a thing now. But you are correct, this is not part of "stock" Android at all.

Comment: Agreed! even some MIUI users who previously had this feature [say its no longer available](https://in.c.mi.com/thread-665531-2-1.html) upon upgrade to 8.1 oreo but I am still on Nougat and I have [this feature](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196265/209414) (first screenshot)

Comment: @acejavelin I think most users need it save battery significantly

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Thanks for the link and as for battery saving, yes it is a possibility but I wonder how relevant it is with a) Improved Doze and b) usage - folks don't even want to be disconnected from Internet :-(

Comment: Two words... "Airplane Mode"... Most modern devices can go several days, even a week plus, if not used and in Airplane Mode without draining the battery. If your still worried about battery life in 2018, you have the wrong device for your usage. :)

Comment: But Airplane Mode can't be easily automated since 4.2, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13766909/72178.

Answer (score 1):

I found it on my Nokia 3 TA-1020 with Android 8.0.0 through the Search feature in Settings: "Scheduled power on & off" which leads to "Scheduled power on & off". I have found no other way of getting to that item.

Update (21-Dec-2018): After updating to Android 8.1.0, that search doesn't work anymore. It seems that feature has now been removed. Pity.

Comment: I still can't find it in "System" or anywhere else on my Nokia, running Android 8.1.0 – it's truly gone. On the other hand, my wife's Oppo A3s running 8.1.0/ColorOS 5.2.1 does have "Automatic On/Off" under "Additional Settings". Weird.

Answer (score 1):

I have just upgraded to Android 8.1 some days ago, and the "Scheduled power on and off" feature has been moved under "System" in the settings (as the whole settings menu has been reordered). Note, that the search also finds it for me. (type "scheduled").

So the feature is in place but does not work anymore, or at least my phone stopped to switch on since upgraded the Android version. Only the switch-off is actually working for me.
If you find the feature, I am curious whether both the power on and off will work for you.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I have Android 8.1.0 and can't see it by either of these methods :-( Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: And asking this question didn't help https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/schedule-power-off-on-for-android-8-oreo

Answer (score 0):

you will find schedule power on off mode in settings right under Developer option. if your developer option is not activated then you can activate it by tapping on Build noumber 6/7 times.